# Unable to appeal for restoration of deleted Facebook app

Tags: facebook

I am unable to restore a deleted facebook app. I have received an email indicating the possibility to restore this app, however the section "Restore Apps" says: "There are no apps available for you to recover. If you don't see the app you're looking for, it means we're not able to restore that app.".

Can someone help me find a way to restore this app.

[image: Restoration indication mail]

[image: App deletion notification]

[image: Empty appeal page]

I tried to visit this page multiple times and logging in with different accounts/credentials we have, but nothing worked. I have already searched the community forums and tried contacting Facebook directly without result.

Comment: _"If you don't see the app you're looking for, it means we're not able to restore that app."_ - doesn't sound like there could be much more to say about this, from the outside.